# Get SPListItem ItemsData

Tags: list, development, splistitem, user

I have the list of items in object `SPListItem item`. Is it possible to extract certain data from the `ListItems` property?

The reason I want to do that is because I have a FieldName "AssignedTo" which returns null, even though I can see its value when debugging when using the following statement:

```
SPField field = item.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName("AssignedTo");
if (field != null)
{

    SPFieldUserValue fieldValue = field.GetFieldValue(item["AssignedTo"].ToString()) as
                                                                                SPFieldUserValue;

    if (fieldValue != null)
    {
        assignToUser = fieldValue.User;
    }
}
```

Now, in the `ListItems` property I can go to `ItemsData` and I can see the value is there, but how can I get it?

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Do you want to get the value from "AssignedTo" column for specific list item?

Comment: As your question is somewhat confusing me. So kindly clear it so i can help you. :)

Comment: @Hardik Yes, that's correct. I'm interested in the value of AssignedTo, but for some unknown reason, it returns null and I can't for the love of me figure out why as I can see the value in 'ItemsData' when debugging. Please ask for more clarification if needed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code should work: (web is a variable that references the web object)

```
 SPFieldUserValue value = 
                new SPFieldUserValue(web, item["AssignedTo"].ToString());
 if (value)
    {
        assignToUser = value.User;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try below code,

```
using (SPSite siteCol = new SPSite("http://server/sites/Contoso"))
    {
        using (SPWeb web = siteCol.RootWeb)
        {
            SPList list = web.GetList("/sites/Contoso/Lists/Books");

            SPListItem item = list.GetItemByIdSelectedFields(3, "Title", "ISBN", "Retail_x0020_Price");

            String bookISBN = (String)item["ISBN"];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SPFieldUserValue userField = item.Fields["AssignedTo"] as SPFieldUser;
string userName = item["AssignedTo"].ToString();

SPFieldUserValue fieldValue = (SPFieldUserValue)userField.GetFieldValue(userName);
SPUser user = fieldValue.User;
```

Taken from http://ethan-deng.blogspot.com/2013/03/get-spuser-from-user-column-there-are.html

Answer (score 2):

You can try below code to get `SPUser` in **AssignedTo** columns for specific item.

> ```
> If(task["Assigned To"] != null)
> {
>     string fieldValue = Convert.ToString(task["Assigned To"]);
>     SPFieldUserValue assignedTo = (SPFieldUserValue)
>     task.Fields["Assigned To"].GetFieldValue(fieldValue);
> }
> ```